# Size of char Array doesn't change(C)

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf

Somehow my program outputs the same size no matter how long the array gets, do you know what i did wrong?

```
char charArray[] = "STRING";
int size = sizeof(charArray) / 2 - 1;
        
printf("%d", size);
```

> Output: 3

(i have to create a program which finds a string in another string thats why i am substracting 1 at the end to find the length of the word i want to find)

Comment: use `%zu` to print the outcome of `sizeof`

Comment: When you define an array in C, it has a fixed length.  Your declaration implicitly sets (and fixes) the length at 7 ("STRING\0" is 7 chars long - you have an invisible NULL on the end).

Comment: What do you mean, "no matter how long the array gets"? What do you think causes the array's size to change? What do you even think an array *is*?

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and some C standard such as [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Provide some [mre] in your next question. Read documentation of your C compiler [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: How did you make the array longer?

Comment: That code does not output 3. It outputs 2 from (7 / 2 - 1).

Comment: Arrays do not automatically grow or shrink as you store things to them - once defined, their size is fixed.  `charArray`'s size is taken from the `"STRING"` initializer, and can only ever hold at most 7 elements, or a 6-character string.  `sizeof` will always evaluate to the same value for an array, regardless of what’s currently stored in it,

Comment: @WeatherVane if the 'array' is, in fact, an 8-byte pointer, that would explain getting 3 every time.  Maybe OP has over-MRE'd?

Comment: @MartinJames good point, in which case code misfires because you can't find the size of an array passed to a function, with `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the length of your string, you could use `strlen` from the string library, of implement your own one:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}
```

with this function, `my_strlen("STRING")` will return 6.

Comment: Don't advise newbies to reimplement stdlib functions. There's no need to reinvent the wheel, especially when they might get it wrong.

Comment: You're totally right

Comment: @underscore_d beginners should learn by writing those functions as it is the best exercise .

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on that one.

Comment: I would not say i am a beginner, i just didnt have to find the length of an array until now...

This is the code i had to use it for: https://onlinegdb.com/B1Y89eYoP